# LoadingTextAnimation requirements to work

Tags: codenameone

I'm referring to the code examples of this tutorial: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/data-loading-placeholders.html

These examples use a `BorderLayout`, but the `LoadingTextAnimation` example don't work using a `BoxLayout.y()`. I suspect that the problem is the minimum height of the `Component` to be replaced with an animated placeholder.

For example, the following code doesn't work:

```
        Form f = new Form("Hello", BoxLayout.y());
        Label profileText = new Label();
        profileText.setText("placeholder");
        f.add(profileText);
        LoadingTextAnimation.markComponentLoading(profileText);
        f.show();
```

But this works fine:

```
        Form f = new Form("Hello", BoxLayout.y());
        Label profileText = new Label(){
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                Dimension dim = super.getPreferredSize();
                int mm = CN.convertToPixels(1);
                Log.p(dim.toString() + " -> width = " + (dim.getWidth() / mm) + " height = " + (dim.getHeight() / mm));
                dim.setHeight(CN.convertToPixels(10));
                Log.p(dim.toString() + " -> width = " + (dim.getWidth() / mm) + " height = " + (dim.getHeight() / mm));
                return dim;
            }
        };
        profileText.setText("placeholder");
        f.add(profileText);
        LoadingTextAnimation.markComponentLoading(profileText);
        f.show();
```

Playing with `dim.setHeight(CN.convertToPixels(...));`, I find that the minimum height should be about 10mm. Is it so? If yes, why? Or are there other requirements? The Javadoc doesn't say anything about that.

Thank you for any explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some adjustments to the LoadingTextAnimation to use the font size and padding of the label it replaces, and this seems to correct the issue.  The commit which fixes this is https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/6e62fb8d267ec2630487cd4e09e3a0045644840f